# Espresso test fails No views in hierarchy

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an issue with Espresso test, I don't know why...

I used Android Studio to generate the test, it generates this with "run > Record Espresso Test" :

```
ViewInteraction buttonSignIn = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.button_sign_in),
                    childAtPosition(
                            allOf(withId(R.id.content_login_relative),
                                    childAtPosition(
                                            withId(R.id.content_login),
                                            0)),
                            2),
                    isDisplayed()));
buttonSignIn.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

This is a part of activity XML :

```
<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/activity_login_register_content_login"
    android:id="@+id/content_login"
    />
```

And a part of activity_login_register_content_login XML

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewLogin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/content_login_relative"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        >
        ...
        <Button
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

"android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: application:id/button_sign_in and Child at position 2 in parent (with id: application:id/content_login_relative and Child at position 0 in parent with id: application:id/content_login) and is displayed on the screen to the user)"

Do you have any idea why I'm facing this issue ?

Thanks you

Comment: have you checked your layout (view hierarchy) with the android device monitor tool? this is normally very helpful to find out how your layout looks like

Comment: Did you  find solution for this?